# CausalImpact plot upper and lower bounds

Tags: causalimpact

Below is a screenshot of causal impact result.

Upper and lower bounds of point wise results plot hovers around 10k and -10k. In summery statistics, sd shows 1879 with 95 CI of -4674 and 2736. Is the discrepancy between range of shaded blue area and 95 CI expected? if so, how should I interpret the shaded blue area?

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For **point effects**, the shaded blue area shows *pointwise* 95% credible intervals, while the summary table reports the 95% credible interval for the *average* effect (mean over the whole post-intervention period). The interval reported in the table is therefore expected to be narrower than the intervals in the plot.

For **cumulative effects**, the table reports the 95% credible interval at the end of the post-intervention period, therefore it agrees with the width of the blue credible interval to the right.